# Как запустить процесс nohup через php скрипт?

Tags: php, linux

Хочу через php скрипт запустить работу в фоне другого скрипта, для этого в **script_1.php** пишу такой код:

```
exec('nohup /opt/php71/bin/php /script_2.php &');
```

И процесс добавляется конечно, но **script_1.php** ждет завершение *exec* (то есть покуда выполниться запускаемый *script_2.php*). А мне не нужно чтобы **script_1.php** ждал выполнения, мне нужно чтобы он просто добавил процесс и завершился сразу же.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А Вы создайте файл php, в котором вызываете 2 скрипта. Тот, что в примере и основной, через подобный синтаксис `&` в конце.

Comment: пробовал. не выходит - все равно ждет выполнения script_2.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В официальной документации https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php к этой функции exec(), есть комментарий в котором рекомендуют поступать следующим образом

```
passthru("nohup /opt/php71/bin/php /script_2.php >> /tmp/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```