# Как через один скрипт php запустить другой скрипт php асинхронно?

Tags: php, exec

Стоит такая задача: запустить скрипт b.php из скрипта a.php асинхронно, не дожидаясь от него ответа. Скрипт b.php выполняется около минуты и просто, с несколькими командами sleep, заменяет данные в бд и делает отправку сообщений.
Нашел несколько вариантов решить свою задачу, например этот: [клик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103528/call-another-php-script-and-return-control-to-user-before-the-other-script-compl)

В общем-то у меня та же задача. Понял, что возможно смогу решить это с помощью:

```
 exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

Мне нужно запустить скрипт b.php с входящими POST или GET параметрами(не важно каким вариантом из этих двух, просто передать массив значений, дальше скрипт уже обработает так, как мне нужно). Но при этом если я запускаю скрипт b.php несколько раз подряд, то, из-за синхронности php, второе выполнение не начнется, пока не завершится первое. Мне же нужно чтобы скрипт начинал выполнение сразу же. Поможет ли мне команда выше в такой ситуации? Если да, то как я могу ее использовать и передать определенные переменные в скрипт b.php? Прошу описать поподробнее ее использование.

Comment: Кто мешает взять и попробовать?

Comment: Мешает неумение работать с этой командой и непонимание что вообще должно стоять на месте переменной $cmd, а также как передать в скрипт нужные переменные.

Comment: Возможно поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-nohup-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82/1075904#1075904

Answer (score 1):

В скрипте a.php получить свой POST. Затем запустить через exec свой b.php с передачей ему данных POST. При вызове b.php через exec.. ты даешь команду терминалу, а браузер продолжает работает с a.php. Это не совсем асинхронность, но близкое к тому.

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

В качестве $cmd будет что-то вроде этого "php /home/bitrix/www.site.com/cron/telegram.php param1=test1 param2=test2"

/dev/null & - тебе в принципе не нужно. Если b.php что-то выводит - можно указать, например, > /home/bitrix/text.txt

Там будет все, что выводит b.php